# Build private maven repo using Docker

Tags: java, maven, docker, maven-docker-plugin

I have jar files for my web application. I need to have those dependency jars in my local maven repository so that I can use them in my applications.  It would be nice to run the local maven repo as a container in my development machine.

Comment: If you intent to use it only on local machine, then what's wrong with `~/.m2/repository` ? I can't image what improvement would be to have it in container

Comment: I have to share it with my team.

Comment: nexus is available as a docker instance.  Very easy to get started with.

Comment: Instead of running a docker container. Using a maven repository in the cloud might be easy. I use https://repsy.io for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach (at least for companies) is:

- Run a Nexus/Artifactory on a company server that holds internal and external artifacts.
- Have a `settings.xml` that points to that Nexus.

The local repository is then only a cache for your Nexus, no need to run any containers.

Comment: Will I be able to run Artifactory in a container

Comment: Never tried, but https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+with+Docker

Comment: Running [Nexus OSS](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/#running) is match easier as it can be done using single container. Artifactory need more of them (if I remember correctly, it needs other for database)

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old post, but we've been maintaining an easy-to-use [Apache Archiva image](https://github.com/xetus-oss/docker-archiva) for quite some time now. You should try it out if you're looking for something with a very small footprint that is easy to get running.

Archiva certainly isn't the most feature-rich maven repo out there, but it's dead simple, free, and you can run it in k8s quite easily.

That said, I agree with @fırat-kÜÇÜk. Unless you need to self host your maven repo, you really should just use a cloud hosted product. There's nothing easier than a subscription service.